# How do I specify a field-name mapping from an Ember model to JSON?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an API that returns:

```
{id: 1, "other-property": 100}
```

My Ember Data object is defined:

```
MyApp.MyThing = DS.Model.extend({
  extId: DS.attr('number'),
  otherProperty: DS.attr('number')})
```

It looks like I can't use `id` as an attribute in an ember model, and using non-identifier field names will cause trouble. So [the guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_attribute-names) suggests I write a `normalizeHash` function.

```
App.MyThingSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeHash: {
    id: function(hash) {
      hash.appId = hash.id;
      delete hash.id;
      return hash;
    },
    otherProperty: function(hash) {
      hash.otherProperty = hash['other-property'];
      delete hash['otherProperty'];
      return hash;
    }
  }
});
```

It doesn't suggest how to re-serialize when sending back over an API. How do I do I create a two-way mapping?

Is there a declarative way to do this? It seems very cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize it with a different name by overriding the [keyForAttribute](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_keyForAttribute) hook:

```
keyForAttribute: function(key) {
    if (key === 'extId') {
        return 'id';
    } else {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know of a better way to do this. The `RESTSerializer` is insanely complicated and I don't really know my way around it. I personally just wrote my own serializer to get rid of all the cruft. It took me 2 to 3 hours to write, but I was much better off in the end as the code was much simpler.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe this isn't built into ember. It seems like the first thing you'd come across using an HTTP API.

Comment: I think it's mostly due to backward-compatibility. Right now they support so many ways of modifying the payload that adding another one could screw up the existing ones.